# Plsql - Evaluate a dynamic string

Tags: oracle, plsql, dynamic-sql, ddl

I need to build a process that creates tables dynamically.

I have this:

```
declare
type array is table of varchar2(30) index by binary_integer;
  a array;
  expression varchar2(2000);
  RESUME_create LONG;  

procedure createTables ( texto in VARCHAR2 ) is 
    begin 
      dbms_output.put_line('the parameter is: ' || texto);
      expression := 'begin ' || texto || '; end;';
      dbms_output.put_line(expression);
      execute immediate expression;    
    end;

RESUME_create   := 'CREATE TABLE RESUME (
     R_Resume_date          DATE         DEFAULT SYSDATE NOT NULL ,
     R_Resume_source        CHAR(3)      DEFAULT ''001'' NOT NULL ,
     R_Resume_channel       CHAR(3)      DEFAULT ''001'' NOT NULL )';  

  createTables('RESUME_create');
end;
/
```

So this is just an example.

So imagine that I need to declare multiples CREATE TABLEs and call the createTable into a loop passing multiples string that the function has to evaluate and execute.

Comment: http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Oracle/0440__PL-SQL-Statements/DynamicDQLwithDBMSSQLpackage.htm

Comment: Do you really need that? Usually global temporary tables are used for this purpose.

Comment: Why do you need to create tables dynamically? Typically, tables should be created outside of PL/SQL (e.g. as part of a one-time deployment script) and not constantly dropped and recreated.

Comment: the idea is get a list with all the tables names (... for example: tablas := tablesarray('RESUME', 'NOTES', 'ITYPE'); ...  ). 

After that declare all the querys into variables like this: `code` RESUME_create := 'CREATE TABLE RESUME (R_Resume_Idate NUMBER(3,0) )'; NOTES_create := 'CREATE TABLE RESUME (R_Resume_Idate NUMBER(3,0) )'; ITYPE_create := 'CREATE TABLE RESUME (R_Resume_Idate NUMBER(3,0) )'; `code` 

After that, into a loop read **tablas**, concatenate "_create" and evaluate into a execute immediate

Comment: @Boneist i need that because i have 50 tables that must created, and i don't want that all sql script be executed one by one (because the guy that prepare that sql script made one .sql for table)

Comment: @Julio how many times are these tables to be created? If it's once, then there's absolutely no issues with having a script that calls other scripts - i.e. you can have your individual table scripts, and then a "master" script that calls them.

Comment: Are you sure you don't want to use Ant or one of its more modern successors to run the build for you?

Comment: @Boneist the point is at this momment we are in development phase, and the team want test all steps, creation , alters, index etc more tan once. Tha is the problem.

Comment: @APC this is a job for a banc, and there is a lot of bureaucracy ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I un understand well, you need to run a set of DDL statements stored in a collection. If so, you can use something like:

```
declare
    type   tArray is table of varchar2(1000) index by pls_integer;
    vArray tArray ;
begin
    vArray(1) := 'create table firstTab  ( a number, b number)';
    vArray(2) := 'create table secondTab ( c number, d varchar2(10))';
    --
    for i in vArray.first .. vArray.last loop
        execute immediate vArray(i);
    end loop;
end;
/
```

Comment: the idea is get a list with all the tables names (... for example: tablas := tablesarray('RESUME', 'NOTES', 'ITYPE'); ...  ). 

After that declare all the querys into variables like this: `code` RESUME_create := 'CREATE TABLE RESUME (R_Resume_Idate NUMBER(3,0) )'; NOTES_create := 'CREATE TABLE RESUME (R_Resume_Idate NUMBER(3,0) )'; ITYPE_create := 'CREATE TABLE RESUME (R_Resume_Idate NUMBER(3,0) )'; `code` 

After that, into a loop read **tablas**, concatenate "_create" and evaluate into a execute immediate